# Dataweave dynamic change values

Tags: dataweave, mule4

how can be this done if I have string like this.

"Processing of job {$jobName} started ${yyyy-MM-dd}"

To get

"Processing of job test-job started 2022-10-11"

Thanks!

Comment: From where are you getting the values of `jobName` and `yyyy-MM-dd`. Are they maintained in a property file? of are they coming from a JSON?

Comment: jobName I get from payload stored in vars.jobName. yyyy-MM-dd should be autogenerated from now()

Comment: Can there be more variables? or is it just `jobName`. If there are more, is this statement true that the placeholder value will ALWAYS be equal to the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use DataWeave string interpolation. Syntax is somewhat different:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var date=now()
---
"Processing of job $(vars.jobName) started $(date as String {format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'})"
```